# android View (actionbar, etc) get pushed up using VItamio player

Tags: android, vitamio

I got a weird bug after using [Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) player in one of my activity. The screen get pushed up when vitamio's media controller appear and it caused my action bar cropped by half.

This is the screenshot before the media controller appear (normal) :

[image]

And this is when the media controller appeared (see my action bar) :

[image]

This is my layout XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MatchDetailActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapperVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
                android:id="@+id/buffer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/probar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!--
             <TextView
            android:id="@+id/download_rate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="" 
            android:visibility="gone"/>

            -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/load_rate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout>



        <!--
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFull"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

        -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/wrapperPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/events"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="EVENTS" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lineups"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="LINEUPS" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/statistics"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="STATISTICS" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTeam1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:text="Team 1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageTeam1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtScore1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="48sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtScore2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="48sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTeam2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:text="Team 2" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageTeam2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/detailPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/ads" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ads"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="ads" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please kindly help me, Thanks for your help.E

Answer (score 2):

-find this line in this file io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController.java
setWindowLayoutType();
-then comment it

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my application as well. I narrowed the problem down to the setWindowLayoutType() method in the Vitamio MediaController. What I did is I commented out the method setWindowLayoutType() in the show() method the problem went away for me. I am still trying to figure out why this is happening but in the mean time hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

you must comment this line setWindowLayoutType(); of
this funtion show ,this function is found in this file io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController.java
;url of this file :https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/blob/master/vitamio/src/io/vov/vitamio/widget/MediaController.java

```
public void show(int timeout) {
    if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null && mAnchor.getWindowToken() != null) {
      if (mPauseButton != null)
        mPauseButton.requestFocus();

      if (mFromXml) {
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
        int[] location = new int[2];

        mAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        Rect anchorRect = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + mAnchor.getWidth(), location[1] + mAnchor.getHeight());

        mWindow.setAnimationStyle(mAnimStyle);
//comment this line below
        setWindowLayoutType();
        mWindow.showAtLocation(mAnchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, anchorRect.left, anchorRect.bottom);
      }
      mShowing = true;
      if (mShownListener != null)
        mShownListener.onShown();
    }
    updatePausePlay();
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

    if (timeout != 0) {
      mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
      mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT), timeout);
    }
  }
```

Comment: url of this file :https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/blob/master/vitamio/src/io/vov/vitamio/widget/MediaController.java